# Responsive HTML & Php Script for a contact form

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm a newbie, I need someone to help me with a PhP script for my below contact form that will send the details to an email address without leaving the contact.html page but a small window saying "submitted"

here is my HTML5 code for a form:

```
<form id="form" class="form" name="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="submit.php">
    <h1>Contact us</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="intro"></div>
        <div id="section0" >
            <div class="field"><label for="Name">Name</label><input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required></div>
            <div class="field"><label for="Email">Email</label><input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required></div>
            <div class="field"><label for="Telephone">Telephone</label><input type="tel" id="Telephone" name="Telephone" required></div>
            <div class="field"><label for="Message">Message</label><textarea id="Message" name="Message" wrap="hard" required></textarea></div>
            <div class="field"><div class="edit-options"><div class="edit"></div><div class="delete"></div></div><label for="Submit">Submit</label><input name="Submit" type="submit" required id="Submit" formaction="send_form_email.php"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
  </div>
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me, as I have wasted money on these online php forms who want to charge all kinds just for a basic contact form.

Thanks

Comment: You can do an Ajax call to a php page to submit the mail

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: I think what you were trying to say was: "I need someone to do all the work for me."

Comment: you want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your replies, no i wasn't after someone to do the work for me i just needed an example or a tutorial but found one from below user.

Comment: Right I have a problem, there is no title in the email when sent i.e. 'No sender' when I submit my form online.  the code is EMAIL;

$header .= 'From: $email';

Answer (score 0):

you can easily find on internet how to put together a contact form, but you will need to upload your site on some server, to check if email is working. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5a_zy_utoFM

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'm new to Php but that video explains it well

Comment: Hi mar1, the video was ace finally got what I wanted but I have a slight problem when i complete the form and press send as a test, it came back to my email as the sender '$email' instead of a name?

Comment: <?php
$to ='myemail@mail.com';
$subject ='Enquiries to website';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Hello my name is $name

$message

from $name my subject is $subject
My contact is $contact
My Email is $email

Comment: EMAIL;

$header = 'From: $email';

if($_POST){
 if($name == '' || $contact == '' || $email == '' || $subject == '' || $message == ''){
 $feedback = 'Please complete the fields'; 
 }else{
     mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
        $feedback = 'Thank you for your enquiry, we will be replying to you very soon.';
  }    
} 

?>